# Why is it taking forever for Ubuntu to log in?

Tags: security, vmware, linux-headers

I just installed Ubuntu in my VMware and I discovered that it is very slow. It didn't even restart after I completed the installation and removed the .iso file, I had to manually shut it down and turn it on from the VM.

Now I have turned it on, entered my login details but it's taking eternity for it to load. It is over 20minutes now. I have shut it down and tried again, the same delay

[image]

Comment: Without knowing anything about the resources allocated to the VM or the host it’s running on — including what it’s doing — will make an accurate answer really difficult to provide. If all else fails, boot into the Live ISO and check to see if there are any error messages in the `syslog` file (on the VM storage) 

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing `ESC` as this should show what its doing, hopefully what its stuck trying to do.   I totally agree with the above comment. We don't have enough information to diagnose.

Comment: thanks, I was able to fix that to an extent by increasing the RAM size of the Ubuntu. Have you any idea why my Firefox can't connect to the internet on Ubuntu?